# fullcalendar added resources get removed on page refresh

Tags: jquery, scheduler, fullcalendar-scheduler

I am using the fullcalendar plugin in order to create a scheduling web app. I have added a custom button in the header in order to add rooms to the resources. These resources do get added, but they get removed if the page is refreshed. Does anyone know why this is happening?

This is the code to add I made to add a new room to the resources.

```
    customButtons: {
              promptResource: {
                  text: '+ room',
                  click: function() {
                      var title = prompt('Room name');
                      if (title) {
                        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addResource', { title: title }, true );
                      }
                  }
              }
          },
```

Comment: You need to save the changes to a database and load these when every time the calendar opens? or did I miss out on something?

Comment: That is possibly what is wrong here, I was just using this for testing purposes until i get my database set up properly. I was under the impression though, that you could just add a resource using this method, that will get added to my resources array within my        $('calendar').fullcalendar({}) setup and stay there. For now, all my resources are hardcoded into my resources array, they do not get read in from a database.

Comment: Yeah im pretty sure you need the database running if you want to do testing after you reload :)

Answer (score 0):

When you refresh or change the view, its charge the origin resource function filtering with the actually resources that you have, if the resource added dont be in you origin resource function it delete the added resources.

The solution is save the resources when you added it.